# The app should try to load fragments when the Navigation Drawer is already closed

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I have been using your android app for a week and it is cool. But I found out that when I click on item in the Navigation Drawer, new fragment is loading while the Navigation Drawer is still closing. This causes small lags on my device. You should try to load your fragments when the Navigation Drawer is already closed.

There are many "methods" to do that but in my app this works like a charm:

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,
            long id) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   displayView(position); 
                }
            }, /*change if you want*/ 350);
        }}
```

Avoid performing expensive operations such as layout during animation as it can cause stuttering:
[Check android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)

Comment: Don't bump with trivial useless edits. Thanks.